# What's an efficient way for matching against a known set of regex in Rust?

Tags: regex, rust

**Context**

I have a large volume of logs coming in that need to be tagged by occurrence of specific content in real-time. To this end I have a long list (100s) of pairs of content-type-names with corresponding sets of manually defined somewhat complex regular expressions. Until now the matching has been done in Python with a dict of pre-compiled regular expressions that are run in list comprehension matching against strings. I want to move this dict and the Regex matching to Rust.

**Question**

What would be an idiomatic and efficient way to check string against these pre-defined regular expressions in Rust, starting off from something like this?

```
let type_map = HashMap::from([
        ("Type 1", r"some-regex"),
        ("Type 2", r"some-regex"),
        ("Type ...", r"some-regex"),
        ("Type 100", r"some-regex"),
    ]);
```

I could loop over each entry, create a Regex struct and apply to string but I have the feeling that this is probably the wrong approach.

**What I've tried**

I'm new to Rust and as such somewhat clueless on how to approach this in a sensible way. I have tried a `HashMap` of `<String, Regex>` Regex structs with `("Type x", Regex::new(r"regex-for-x").unwrap()" entries. I am using the fancy-regex create for lookarounds.

Comment: Most likely idiomatic way is to `use regex::RegexSet`, but in this case you will deal with indices of regex instead of string keys "Type N".

Comment: If you don't care which regex matches, combine them all into a single regex, join `|`, regex1, 2, 3, 4, ... Then refactor them into compact regex using this tool https://imgur.com/a/hbwfuKZ. After it is refactored, store the constant string by embedding it  into your code.

Comment: It's pretty unlikely that you need to refactor the regex. The `regex` crate uses finite automata, not backtracking, where that sort of refactoring tends to help a lot more. The `regex` also does its own form of refactoring for you.

Comment: You can give a link to your regex's, I can make a single, refactored one out of it.
These demo's are 2 years old. The routines have all been updated multiple times.
https://regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_FactDevSamps/ReFactSamp_Emoj_TernAndPipeFact.mp4
Miscellaneous others 
https://regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_FactDevSamps/ReFactSamp_1.mp4,

https://regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_FactDevSamps/ReFactSamp_2.mp4,

https://regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_FactDevSamps/ReFactSamp_3.mp4,

https://regexformat.com/Dnl/_Samples/_FactDevSamps/ReFactSamp_5.mp4,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the [hyperscan](https://docs.rs/hyperscan/latest/hyperscan/) crate ([docs](https://intel.github.io/hyperscan/dev-reference/index.html)), you may stitch your patterns together through the [`patterns!`](https://docs.rs/hyperscan/latest/hyperscan/macro.patterns.html) macro. But be careful, its syntax & semantics differs from the `regex` crate, i.e. you should not put `.*` inside.

```
let pattern = pattern! {"test"; CASELESS | SOM_LEFTMOST};
let db: BlockDatabase = pattern.build().unwrap();
let scratch = db.alloc_scratch().unwrap();

db.scan("some test data", &scratch, |id, from, to, _flags| {
    assert_eq!(id, 0);
    assert_eq!(from, 5);
    assert_eq!(to, 9);

    println!("found pattern {} : {} @ [{}, {})", id, pattern.expression, from, to);

    Matching::Continue
}).unwrap();
```

Comment: I will be needing negative look-ahead but nevertheless, I can utilize this in another section. Thank you!